# How can I visualize single trees from a random survival forest?

Tags: r, ggplot2, random-forest

I have trained a random survival forest using the R package randomForestSRC. For publication, I would like to visualize some selected trees, preferably using the ggraph package, much like here: https://shiring.github.io/machine_learning/2017/03/16/rf_plot_ggraph

The randomForest package has a convenient function randomForest::getTree, but so far, I have not found an analogue function in in randomForestSRC.
How are the trees stored in the random survival forest, and how I can access them?  I'd be grateful for any hints!